# Is this sentence using relative clauses correct grammatically?

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses

> The winner of the competition is the person who gets the cheese first, which is the prize.

Comment: try- The winner of the competition gets the cheese first which is the prize.

Comment: "There is no additional prize for the person who gets the cheese first."

Comment: It's clumsy but probably "legal".

Comment: Whoever first gets the cheese, which is also the prize, is the winner. (Just how I might rephrase it)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is just about grammatical. The reason I hesitate is that the word *first* gets in the way, between *cheese* and its relative pronoun *which*, making the whole thing a bit clumsy.

It would perhaps be better to say ***The winner is the first to get the cheese, which is the prize.*** That way it is perfectly grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

The relative clause should be immediately after the noun it modifies:

> The winner of the competition is the person who gets the cheese, which is the prize, first.

See [Grammar Bytes](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/relativeclause.htm) for a tutorial on the user of the relative clause.

Answer (score 0):

I will correct the sentence to make the relative clause after the noun:

> The winner of the competition is *the first person who gets* **the cheese,
>   which is the prize**.